# How to differentiate between error due to authorization and wrong server url in OpenCMIS?

Tags: sharepoint, alfresco, cmis, opencmis, apache-chemistry

By default, the inmemory repository has no username or password. Is there a way I can setup a username and password for it?

If not, the `SessionFactory.createSession()` always throws a `CmisBaseException`.
How do i differentiate between failure due to wrong server url and authentication error?
The error due to wrong server url contained a `CmisConnectionException`. I'm unable to find out what exception class is used in case of wrong username and password.

Please reply as early as possible.

Comment: The in-memory server is normally only used for testing and debugging. Just to check - you're not trying to use it for production or anything like that are you?

Comment: No.. I'm using it for debugging only. But, I wan't to be able to differentiate between error due to wrong credentials and error due to wrong server url. I did not find any documentation regarding this. So, I thought I could set an username and password and try to login through my client with wrong user name and password, so that I could differentiate between the errors caught

Answer (score 1):

Although I could not change the login credentials for the inmemory repository, I was able to differentiate between authorization error and wrong url error.

Here is what I did:

I tried logging into a nuxexo test server through my client with wrong user credentials:
I caught a `CmisBaseException`. But, on obtaining the class name of the exception, it is: `CmisUnauthorizedException`

I tried with a wrong server url:
I caught a `CmisBaseException`, But, the class name of the exception is `CmisConnectionException`.

So, one can make use of this property to differentiate between the two errors.